# Get List of activities in CRM from week 36

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a list of actions for week 36 of 2022 from the entire database list ("Сustomers" data base)

I tried to do it this way, but it gives out only the activity of the first day of the week

```
DATEADD(week, 36, '2022')
```

Comment: Invest in a calendar table, then `JOIN` to that. When weeks start is very subjective, depending on language settings and business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for, read more about [DATEADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp) function:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    crm_table
WHERE
    action_time
BETWEEN 
    DATEADD(week, 36, '2022') 
AND 
    DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(week, 37, '2022'))
```